# Google chart with ajax call is not working in drupal

Tags: php, jquery, html, drupal, charts

I am tring to use google chart with drupal by an ajax call but it not showing me anything . When i am checking the ajax-url (localhost/drupal/gethello) in browser it is making the graph correctly.

please see my code  and ajax call -:

```
    function hello_menu(){
    $items = array();
    $items['hellopage'] = array(

        'title'=>'My Hello Page',
        'description'=>'Hello users',
        'page callback'=>'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments'=>array('show_hello_form'),
        'access callback'=>'user_access',
        'access arguments'=>array('access content'),
        'type'=>MENU_NORMAL_ITEM        
    );
    $items['gethello'] = array(
        'page callback'=>'hello_ajaxCallHandler',
        'access callback'=>'user_access',
        'access arguments'=>array('access content'),
        'type'=>MENU_CALLBACK       
    );

    Return $items;  
}



/*ajax response*/
function hello_ajaxCallHandler(){
    echo "<h2>Ajax complete see the response -: </h2>".filter_xss($_GET['name']).show_charts();
}

/* simple chart generated by google api */
function show_charts(){

return <<<EOD

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          function drawChart() {

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
              ['Work',     11],
              ['Eat',      2],
              ['Commute',  2],
              ['Watch TV', 2],
              ['Sleep',    7]
            ]);

            var options = {
              title: 'My Daily Activities'
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
        </script>
        </head>
        <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
EOD;
```

Here is the ajax call hello.js in ..modules/hello/hello.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery("#submitAjaxButton").click(function(){

    //alert("you clicked on the button");
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:Drupal.settings.basePath + 'gethello',
        data:{
            name: jQuery("#edit-name").val(),
        },
        success:function(data){
            //ajax return value  
            //alert(data);
            jQuery("#msg-display-area").html(data);
        }

    });
});

});
```

Comment: `filter_xss` strips out script tags.

Comment: filter_xss($_GET['name']).show_charts(); filter_xss only apply for $_GET['name']

Comment: You will need to show the full code. How you make the Ajax request, Drupal behaviors if any, and the `show_hello_form`.

Comment: is there any way with which i can send you file on  stackoverfloew

Comment: The obviously missing part is how you make the Ajax request. Whether it is Drupal.ajax or the raw jQuery Ajax. Pastebin?